# Select all the checkbox group - react native

Tags: react-native

How can you make select all the checkboxes if selectAll checkbox is true and if any one of the other checkbox is tapped, how to unselect the selectAll checkbox?

Please have a look at the code [here](https://snack.expo.io/@codebyte99/checkboxselectall).

Thankyou in advance.

## App.js

```
const data = {
  status: true,
  data: [
    {
      id: 1
    },
    {
      id: 2
    }
  ]
};

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectedBoxes: [],
    checkAll: false,
  };

  valueChange = checkAll => {
    this.setState({
      checkAll,
    });
  };

  onUpdate = (id) => {
    this.setState(previous => {
      let selectedBoxes = previous.selectedBoxes;
      let index = selectedBoxes.indexOf(id);
      if (index === -1) {
        selectedBoxes.push(id) 
      } else {
        selectedBoxes.splice(index, 1) 
      }
      return { selectedBoxes }; 
    }, () => console.log('abc', this.state.selectedBoxes)); 
  }

  render() {
    const { checkAll } = this.state;
    return (
      <View>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <CheckBox
            onValueChange={check => this.valueChange(check)}
            value={this.state.checkAll}
          />
          <Text> Select All</Text>
        </View>
        {data.data.map((item, index) => {
          return <CheckBoxComponent index={index +1} onUpdate={this.onUpdate.bind(this, item.id)} />;
        })}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

## CheckBox component

```
export default class CheckBoxComponent extends React.Component{
    state = {
      checkValue: false
    }

    valueChange = (check) => {
      this.setState({ checkValue: !this.state.checkValue})
      this.props.onUpdate();
    }

    render() {
      const { checkAll } = this.props;
        return (
          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row'}}>
            <CheckBox
              onValueChange={(check) => this.valueChange(check)}
              value={this.state.checkValue}
            />
            <Text> {this.props.index}</Text>
          </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you do pass `passedCheckValue` from `App.js` file, your `CheckBoxComponent` will just render the `passedCheckValue` what ever we will pass to it.

suppose value is : `this.props.passedCheckValue`

and just add

```
componentDidMount(){
   this.setState({ checkValue: this.props.passedCheckValue})
}
```

Comment: After that if the other checkbox is selected, it functions wrong.

Comment: you have to create a data set , like user-list-data set to handle all that.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by checking if the id of checkbox is included in the selectedBoxes array or not?

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectedBoxes: [],
    checkAll: false,
  };

  valueChange = checkAll => {
    this.setState({
      checkAll,
    });
    this.onUpdateAll(checkAll);
  };

  onUpdate = id => {
    this.setState(
      previous => {
        let selectedBoxes = previous.selectedBoxes;
        let index = selectedBoxes.indexOf(id);
        if (index === -1) {
          selectedBoxes.push(id);
        } else {
          selectedBoxes.splice(index, 1);
        }
        return { selectedBoxes };
      },
      () => {
        console.log('abc', this.state.selectedBoxes);
        if (data.data.length === this.state.selectedBoxes.length) {
          this.setState({
            checkAll: true,
          });
        } else {
          this.setState({
            checkAll: false,
          });
        }
      }
    );
  };

  onUpdateAll = checkAll => {
    let allSelectedArray = [];
    if (checkAll) {
      data.data.map((item, index) => {
        allSelectedArray.push(item.id);
      });
      this.setState(
        {
          selectedBoxes: allSelectedArray,
        },
        () => console.log('bcd', this.state.selectedBoxes)
      );
    } else {
      this.setState(
        {
          selectedBoxes: allSelectedArray,
        },
        () => console.log('cde', this.state.selectedBoxes)
      );
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { checkAll, selectedBoxes } = this.state;
    return (
      <View>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <CheckBox
            onValueChange={check => this.valueChange(check)}
            value={this.state.checkAll}
          />
          <Text> Select All</Text>
        </View>
        {data.data.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <CheckBoxComponent
              index={index + 1}
              onUpdate={this.onUpdate.bind(this, item.id)}
              selectedBoxes={selectedBoxes}
              id={item.id}
            />
          );
        })}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

CheckBoxComponent.js

```
class CheckBoxComponent extends React.Component{

    valueChange = (check) => {
      this.props.onUpdate();
    }

    render() {
      const { checkAll, selectedBoxes, id } = this.props;
        return (
          <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row'}}>
            <CheckBox
              onValueChange={(check) => this.valueChange(check)}
              value={selectedBoxes.includes(id)}
            />
            <Text> {this.props.index}</Text>
          </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this complete example which I modified according to your requirements

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Text, View, CheckBox } from "react-native";
import CheckBoxComponent from "./components/CheckBoxComponent";

const data = {
  status: true,
  data: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Bill Gates",
      roll: 101
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Steve Jobs",
      roll: 102
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Linus Torvalds",
      roll: 103
    }
  ]
};

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectedBoxes: []
  };

  valueChange = () => {
    this.setState({
      selectedBoxes: this.state.selectedBoxes.length != data.data.length ? data.data.map(item => item.id) : []
    });
  };

  onUpdate = id => {
    this.setState(previous => {
      let selectedBoxes = previous.selectedBoxes;
      let index = selectedBoxes.indexOf(id);
      if (index === -1) {
        selectedBoxes.push(id);
      } else {
        selectedBoxes.splice(index, 1);
      }
      return { selectedBoxes };
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { selectedBoxes } = this.state;
    return (
      <View>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
          <CheckBox
            onValueChange={this.valueChange}
            value={selectedBoxes.length == data.data.length}
          />
          <Text> Select All</Text>
        </View>
        {data.data.map((item, index) => (
          <CheckBoxComponent
            index={index + 1}
            onUpdate={() => this.onUpdate(item.id)}
            isChecked={!!selectedBoxes.find(obj => obj == item.id)}
          />
        ))}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**CheckBox component**

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, CheckBox } from "react-native";

class CheckBoxComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { index, isChecked, onUpdate } = this.props;
    return (
      <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
        <CheckBox 
          onValueChange={() => onUpdate(index)} 
          value={isChecked} 
        />
        <Text> {index}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default CheckBoxComponent;
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.