# How do you use checkbox in map function in React Native?

Tags: react-native

My current code is like this.

```js
export default class All extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [],
      checkedItems: new Map(),
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(id) {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({ checkedItems: prevState.checkedItems.set(id, true) }));
    console.log(this.state.checkedItems);
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const items = ...;
    this.setState({ items });
  }

   render() {
     const { items } = this.state;

     return (
       <Container>
         <Content>
           <View>
             {items.map((item) => (
               <View key={item.id}>
                 <Text>{item.name}</Text>
                 <View>
                   <CheckBox
                     checked={this.state.checkedItems.get(item.id)}
                     onPress={() => this.handleChange(item.id)}
                   />
                 </View>
               </View>
             ))}
           </View>
         </Content>
       </Container>
     );
   }
}
```

I would like to know how to uncheck.
Also, when I firstly check, console.log() in handleChange() outputs Map {}.
Is it correct?

Or if you know better way bay to use checkbox in map function, plz tell me.

I would appreciate it if you could give me advices.

Comment: this might help you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60927710/9432559

Comment: Thanks! It helped me a lot. appreciate it.

Comment: If that answer has solved your question please consider upvoting it.